# Micronaut bean conditionals using env

Tags: java, micronaut

I'm working on an micronaut app and I'm using conditional beans using the `@Requires(env="test")`, `@Requires(env="development")` and `@Requires(env="prod")` but when I try to run my application I keep getting the: 
`Caused by: io.micronaut.context.exceptions.NonUniqueBeanException: Multiple possible bean candidates found:`

does conditional bean suppport env for it ?

Comment: Did you specify the environment correctly? It works for me on a similar fashion. Try to turn this `io.micronaut.context.condition` into `debug` to see what's going on. Also, what Micronaut version are you using?

Comment: I'm using version 1.1.3, I have enabled logs and I see that 2 of the 3 beans I defined do not fufill the conditions

Comment: can you provide more details how to reproduce ?

Comment: Found the error, it was a problem in my own code. Can we please close the question thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Micronaut test conditional beans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56936903/micronaut-test-conditional-beans)

Comment: @elcharrua What was the problem in your code? I am trying to do the same thing and getting the same error and the I don't quite understand the documentation.

Comment: Yes it was a problem in my code