# Micronaut test conditional beans

Tags: java, micronaut

I'm working on and micronaut application, and I want to test a production bean.
I have a bean that is conditional using `@Requires(env="production"` and another that loads when `@Requires(notEnv="production")` that is a simple mock of production. Is there a way in micronaut to mock enviroment so the production bean is created so that I can test it?

Comment: FYI... At https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56908228/micronaut-bean-conditionals-using-env @elcharrua indicated that the problem was in their own code.

Comment: Have you tried @MicronautTest(environments= {"production"}) on your test?
It seems like it should do what you need